# java list (used to convert bo objects to database objects)

Tags: hibernate

i am getting error as type mismatch cant convert from void to list in below code.. please help me how to solve it?

```
public static List<roleBO> convertBOTODOCreateRolebo(List<roleDO> role) 
{
   java.lang.reflect.Type targetListType = new TypeToken<List<roleBO>>() {}.getType();
   List<roleBO> roleboss =new ModelMapper().map(role, targetListType);
   return roleboss;
}
```

Comment: check map function. It returns void. So you can't associate List<roleBO> in this way.

Comment: @Handi can you please explain how it works, i am confused lot.

Comment: @joe,  what went wrong with map function?..

Comment: Goes with mouse on map function and check its signature. I suppose the return type is void

Comment: i will explain what i have done, first created bo class and then do class, and created an interface, and implemented the methods of interface in another class, now want to convert bo to do, but getting error

Comment: shall i share all code

Answer (score 0):

Change function to:

```
public static List<roleBO> convertBOTODOCreateRolebo(List<roleDO> role) 
{
    List<roleBO> roleboss = role.stream().
        map(i -> mapRole(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return roleboss;
}
```

And create function in same class:

```
private static roleBO mapRole(roleDO role) {
    roleBO result = new roleBO();
    // here set properties of result object from properties of role object
    return result;
}
```